# save output into dataframe with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, pandas

I'm new to web scraping. I'm trying to scrape data from the news site.

I have this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import requests

detik_url = "https://news.detik.com/indeks/2"
detik_url

html = requests.get(detik_url)

bsobj = soup(html.content, 'lxml')
bsobj

for link in bsobj.findAll("h3"):
  print("Headline : {}".format(link.text.strip()))

links = []
for news in bsobj.findAll('article',{'class':'list-content__item'}):
  links.append(news.a['href'])

for link in links:
  page = requests.get(link)
  bsobj = soup(page.content)
  div = bsobj.findAll('div',{'class':'detail__body itp_bodycontent_wrapper'})
  for p in div:
    print(p.find('p').text.strip())
```

How do I utilize a Pandas Dataframe to store the obtained content into a CSV file?

Comment: Do you want to store it in a pandas dataframe or do you want to write collected data into csv file OR do you want to implement pandas dataframe here to write in a csv file? Because 'Pandas dataframe csv' is unclear.

Comment: I want to implement pandas to write in a csv file sir, sorry

Comment: You can try the answer which I have written. Alternatively, I have added one more way to write to CSV, i.e. storing data in NumPy arrays, which takes less space than a pandas dataframe and utilizing pandas dataframe to write to csv.  Alternatively, you can also try NumPy array comprehension to generate your array and avoid the step to convert to NumPy array before writing into a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your content in a pandas dataframe, and then write the structure to a csv file.

Suppose you want to save all the text in your `p.find('p').text.strip()`, along with the headline in a csv file, you can store your headline in any variable (say `head`):

So, from your code:

```
for link in links:
  page = requests.get(link)
  bsobj = soup(page.content)
  div = bsobj.findAll('div',{'class':'detail__body itp_bodycontent_wrapper'})
  for p in div:                 # <----- Here we make the changes
    print(p.find('p').text.strip())
```

In the line shown above, we do the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create an empty array to store all the data

generated_text = []  # create an array to store your data

for link in links:
  page = requests.get(link)
  bsobj = soup(page.content)
  div = bsobj.findAll('div',{'class':'detail__body itp_bodycontent_wrapper'})
    for p in div:
        # print statement if you want to see the output
        generated_text.append(p.find('p').text.strip())  # <---- save the data in an array


# then write this into a csv file using pandas, first you need to create a 
# dataframe from our list

df = pd.DataFrame(generated_text, columns = [head])

# save this into a csv file

df.to_csv('csv_name.csv', index = False)
```

Also, instead of the for loop, you can directly use list comprehensions and save to your CSV.

```py
# instead of the above snippet, replace the whole `for p in div` loop by

# So from your code above:
.....
    bsobj = soup(page.content)
    div = bsobj.findAll('div',{'class':'detail__body itp_bodycontent_wrapper'})
  # Remove the whole  `for p in div:` and instead use this:

    df = pd.DataFrame([p.find('p').text.strip() for p in div], columns = [head])
....

df.to_csv('csv_name.csv', index = False)
```

Also, you can convert your array generated from list comprehension to a numpy array and directly write it to a csv file:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# On a side note: 
# convert your normal array  to numpy array or use list comprehension to make a numpy array, 
# also there are faster ways to convert a normal array to numpy array which you can explore,
# from there you can write to a csv

pd.DataFrame(nparray).to_csv('csv_name.csv'))
```